# Remove invisible space

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to remove the elements with a transition. However there's still a gap.

```js
function handleClick() {
  var el1 = document.getElementById('answer-0')
  var el2 = document.getElementById('answer-1')
  el1.classList.add("out");
  el2.classList.add("out");
}

var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("answer");

var myFunction = function() {
  var attribute = this.getAttribute("data-myattribute");
  alert(attribute);
};

var select = document.getElementById('answer-2')

select.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
```

```css
* {
  transition: all 1s;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.answer {
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

@keyframes leave {
  0% {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
}

.out {
  animation: leave .3s forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <button id='answer-0' class='answer'>
       answer
      </button>
  <button id='answer-1' class='answer'>
       answer
      </button>
  <button id='answer-2' class='answer'>
       click this
      </button>
</div>
```

Link to fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/h5j302dc/19/

I've tried adding a second animation with a delay that adds position: absolute which does get rid of that space however it 'snaps' and doesn't transition.

How can I get rid of that gap from the button that says 'click me' without using transform or negative margins?

Comment: which gap u want to remove?

Comment: inside the click function, add this in the end: `this.style.margin="0"`

Comment: are u expecting like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ptek0bz2/1/

Comment: Sorry should have been more explicit, the gap I'm trying to remove is the distance from the 'click me' button after it's been clicked - currently even though the elements above are no longer visible and the height is set to 0 for those items there is an 'invisible' space.

Expected is when the elements above are either removed from the DOM or position absolute. However those are not options since when those items have broken the flow in their container the click me button does not 'slide' up.